# PHP - How to set changed variables to new array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the output array to be set as a new array with the updated (sorted) output. The purpose of this is to get the new variable to be ordered: [0,1,2,3,4] as now it is being sorted by the key and therefore the order of the actual array has shifted, so its more like: [3,1,4,2]. The code is listed below:

```
//Retrieve what is scored from the game
$name = $_GET["name"];
$score = $_GET["score"];

//Read a text file into an array, with each line in a new element 
$filename = "score.txt"; 
$lines = array(); 
$file = fopen($filename, "r"); 
while(!feof($file)) {
    //read file line by line into a new array element 
    $lines[] = explode("|",fgets($file));
} 
fclose ($file);

//Append $name and $score into $lines
$lines[] = array($score,$name);

//Sort it from high to low
arsort($lines);

//Removes the 11th Highscore - As it is base 0, the 11th term is the 10th array
//unset($lines[10]);

//Remove the \n from the names - rtrim
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $lines[$x][1] = rtrim($lines[$x][1]);
    $lines[$x][0] = intval($lines[$x][0]);
} 

//print_r($lines);
echo json_encode($lines);
```

The score.txt contains the following:

`35|Nathan
50|Matt
45|Sam
20|Jono
40|Bob
30|Roman
25|Zac
15|Larry
10|Thomas
5|Josh`

The output is currently the following (including the added $name and $score):

```
{"10":[55,"Ball"],"1":[50,"Matt"],"2":[45,"Sam"],"4":[40,"Bob"],"0":[35,"Nathan"],"5":[30,"Roman"],"6":[25,"Zac"],"3":[20,"Jono"],"7":[15,"Larry"],"8":[10,"Thomas"],"9":[5,"Josh"]}
```

As you can see, it orders it by their score: 55,50,45 and the array is just reordered: 10,1,2.

How can I have the same output, but now the output would be:

```
{"0":[55,"Ball"],"1":[50,"Matt"],"2":[45,"Sam"],"3":[40,"Bob"],"4":[35,"Nathan"],"5":[30,"Roman"],"6":[25,"Zac"],"7":[20,"Jono"],"8":[15,"Larry"],"9":[10,"Thomas"],"10":[5,"Josh"]}
```

The output is now: 0,1,2,3.. which is ordered from highest high score: 55,50,45...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[arsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) would reverse order AND maintain index key association, I think what you're looking for is [rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) it will reverse sort the array and reset the index key association

Change the following bit in your code to use `rsort()`

```
//Sort it from high to low
rsort($lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Before 'json_encode($lines)' code, Put below code:-
$lines_temp = array();
foreach($lines as $k=>$v){
$lines_temp[] = $lines[$k];
}
$lines = $lines_temp;
echo json_encode($lines);
```